# How to change inner properties of JavaScript Pong game onClick

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have this Pong game in JS: https://codepen.io/Raitar/pen/EbLbYK?editors=0010

I want to make a dramatic effect onClick, computer's paddle should get bigger, while players should get tiny-small, while the drama music starts playing. I already have all except for the working fuction to manipulate paddle sizes.

Here is my function so far:

```
function play() {
var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
    Player.paddle = (175, 180, 10, 10);
    Computer.paddle = (175, 180, 10, 10);
}else{
  audio.pause();
}
}
```

For the rest please see the codepen link, it's quite long.

How do I change paddle sizes onclick?

Comment: You seem to be having some other general bugs, but in your particular code you have invalid JavaScript. You probably just want to update the x/y/width/height. You can do that in one line via Object.assign: `Object.assign( player.paddle, { x: 175, y: 180, width: 10, height: 10 } )`.

Comment: Just tried it, it makes paddle disappear, Edit: or actually moves paddle upwards, guess ill play around with object.assign

Comment: Since you said you just want to change the size, you can exclude x and y: `Object.assign( player.paddle, { width: 10, height: 10 } )`. Once you get to so few properties, however, you can just do `player.paddle.width = 10;`, etc.

Comment: Allright all working now, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code:

```
function play() {
var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
    Object.assign( player.paddle, { width: 10 } )
    Object.assign( computer.paddle, { width: 200 } )   
}else{
  audio.pause();
    Object.assign( player.paddle, { width: 100 } )
    Object.assign( computer.paddle, { width: 100 } )       
}
}
```